# SwiftUI - How to change the button's image on click?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I'm trying to make it so that when I click a button (that is part of a list of other buttons), the image for the clicked button changes from "star" to "star.fill". Please help!

```
ForEach(pies, id: \.self) { pie in
    Button(action: {
        // some action
    }) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "star")
        Text(pie)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I have a play/pause button.
The button image changes depending on if it is playing or not.

In my View I have a variable:

```
@State var isPlaying : Bool = false
```

Then, whenever you click the button, `isPlaying` is changing -> if it was true it becomes false and vice versa. The button image is set by `ternary operator`.

```
Button(action: {
   self.isPlaying.toggle()
}) {
    Image(systemName: self.isPlaying == true ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom button style to determine which image is displayed based on the pressed state:

```swift
struct ImageButtonStyle: ButtonStyle { 
    var image: String
    var pressedImage: String

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
      let displayImage = configuration.isPressed ? pressedImage : image
      return Image(displayImage, bundle: Bundle(for: SomeClassInYourApp.self))
    }
}
```

For ease of use, you can create a view which uses the button style:

```swift
struct ImageButton: View {
    
    var image: String
    var pressedImage: String
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.action) { }
            .buttonStyle(ImageButtonStyle(image: image, pressedImage: pressedImage)
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```swift
ImageButton(
    image: "your_unpressed_image", 
    pressedImage: "your_pressed_image", 
    action: { ... }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `@State` variable to store the image name and change it on button click:

```
@State var imageName: String = "star"

ForEach(pies, id: \.self) { pie in
      Button(action: {
          self.imageName = "star.fill"
       }) {
       HStack {
           Image(systemName: imageName)
           Text(pie)
           Spacer()
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this wouldn't solve my issue because it would change all buttons under the ForEach to star.fill when one of the buttons are clicked. My goal is to have only the clicked button change it's image. Do you know what can be done here?

Comment: Use a different variable for each button? Or even better an array.

Comment: In SwiftUI, Button appears to be one of the few Views that are not built upon UIKit. The upside is that the Button in SwiftUI is a very flexible construct. The downside of this is that it does not support the concept of state (along with different images/labels for clicked/not) that is built-in to UIKit buttons and, at least in the current version of SwiftUI, you would really need to drive the button image names from an external state model as pawello2222 says.