# Radiobuttons in List swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, radio-button

Im displaying data from server and need to display the options in radiobuttons. But default none of the button should be selected. I was able to display radiobuttons. But when a particular button is clicked, only its image should be changed. Though with my code all the other button images too change. I have gone through some references [SwiftUI - How to change the button's image on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220494/swiftui-how-to-change-the-buttons-image-on-click), but couldn't get it work. As am a newbie to SwiftUI, strucked here.

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State var imageName: String = "radio-off"

    var body: some View {
        List(vwModel.OpnChoice.ItemList) { opn in
            VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                ForEach(opn.Choices.indices, id: \.self) { row in
                    Button(action: {
                        print("\(opn.Choices[row].ChoiceId)")
                        self.imageName = "radio-On"
                    }) {
                        Image(imageName)
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)           
                    }

                    Text(opn.Choices[row].ChoiceName)   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please name you variables with a lowercase letter. It's very confusing to see `vwModel.OpnChoice.ItemList` and not see it as a Type. It clearly isn't a type here and so should be `vwModel.opnChoice.itemList`. Same for `opn.choices`. And `opn.choices[row].choiceId`.

Comment: @Fogmeister ; from the server I get response in ItemList, so in  Model I took as struct OptionsandChoiceList: Decodable{
    
    let ItemList:[OptionsandChoices]  
}.

Comment: If I give like what u said ; lowercase to itemList ; I'm not getting response from server

Comment: Your server is returning JSON. They may or may not have conventions around how they name their data. But in Swift you do. A property begins with a lower case letter. :D If you are decoding the JSON then you can use `CodingKeys` to match the JSON names to the names in your Swift objects.

Comment: Check out the section... "Mapping different key names" in here... https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet 

Answer (score 2):

As you are working with indices anyway, add a `@Published` property to your view model which contains the selected index.

Then set the index in the button action. The redraw of the view sets the button at the selected index to the on-state and the others to the off-state.

As I don't know your environment this is a simplified stand-alone view model and view with SF Symbols images

```
class VMModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedOption = -1
    
    var numberOfOptions = 5
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vwModel = VMModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading) {
            ForEach(0..<vwModel.numberOfOptions, id: \.self) { opn in
                Button(action: {
                    vwModel.selectedOption = opn
                    print("index \(opn) selected")
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: opn == vwModel.selectedOption ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Update:

Meanwhile you can use a Picker with the `.radioGroup` modifier

```
enum Choice {
    case one, two, three
}
```

---

```
struct ListView: View {
    @State private var choice : Choice = .one

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $choice, label: Text("Select an option:")) {
            Text("One").tag(Choice.one)
            Text("Two").tag(Choice.two)
            Text("Three").tag(Choice.three)
        }.pickerStyle(.radioGroup)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that radioGroup isn't available in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are storing a single @State property "imageName" for the entire list. And then when any of the buttons in the list are tapped you are changing that single property. Which will affect all the buttons.

I'd suggest removing this property and putting something into the viewModel.

You appear to have a view model with an array called `vwModel.opnChoice.itemList`.

There are multiple ways of making this work. You could stop a boolean in the `itemList` to say whether each item is selected or not. But, as you want it to work like radio buttons what might be better is to have a property on the `vwModel` like `selectedItem`.

The button could then do...

```
vwModel.selectedItemId = opn.choices[row].choiceId
```

Then you button `Label` would be...

```
Image(vsModel.selectedItemId == opn.choices[row].choiceId ? "radio-on" : "radio-off")
  .renderingMode(.original)
  .resizable()
  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
  .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
```

This would allow you to toggle the button when it is tapped and should turn the other buttons off.