# How can I create a Button in a Swift View that will change its icon image as it toggles

Tags: swiftui

I would like to know how to have a Button (with a capitol B) in a Swift View so that the icon changes as it is tapped. In this extract of my code, I can confirm that my_player.isPlaying does change from true to false to true .... as I tap on this button. Unfortunately this always displays the pause_icon using this Image() syntax below.  I've seen something like this in previous ViewControllers using IBOutlet buttons using syntax something like this that do change the button icon but in Swift Views (which this is the first time I'm coding using them) it does not change as a result of isPlaying changing.  Any suggestions?

struct myview: View {
@EnvironmentObject var my_player: MusicPlayer

```
var body: some View {
    let play_icon = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "play.png")
    let pause_icon = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "pause.png")
    let button_size : CGFloat = 60
    VStack {
            Button(action: {
                my_player.play_pause_music()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    **Image(uiImage: my_player.isPlaying ? pause_icon : play_icon)**
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: button_size)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've googled around but everything that shows up is in relation to ViewController IBOutlet buttons

Comment: Is your `MusicPlayer`, a `class MusicPlayer: ObservableObject` and
 does it have a `@Published var isPlaying = false`.
 Show the code for your `MusicPlayer`, how you declare it,
 and how you pass it to the parent of `myview`.

Comment: Your code looks correct for me, as @workingdogsupportUkraine said, we'd need to see your `MusicPlayer` class to ensure it's working as intended

Comment: I don't know how you searched but a quick googling for "swiftui button change icon" gives me this as first match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220494/swiftui-how-to-change-the-buttons-image-on-click So your approach works, and as the others have stated, it's probably the variable updating that's not working; which is probably the number 1 SwiftUI question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  Yes the class MusicPlayer was an ObservableObject but I did not have @Published  on the line delarning var isPlaying = false.  Its working as it should now.